# Drupal: When I run drush updb then Image Style folders deleted from S3 bucket, I am using S3fs module

Tags: amazon-s3, drupal

When I run drush updb then Image Style folders deleted from S3 bucket, I am using S3fs module.

Steps-
a) Upgrade UAT Drupal from 8.3. to 8.9
b) connected code with Latest Prod sanitised database
c) run drush updb
d) after successfully run, I have checked and found that my prod s3 Style images are missing. Only from this folders only.

Any one can help on it?

I have found some following issues but not sure why its happened: [Missing image styles during "Media" install causes issues in media form and view display.](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923664)

Comment: I think what happened in my case:
Step-1: upgrade UAT env with 8.3 to 8.9 
step-2: Taken production database into new host and connect with UAT code.
step-3   run drush updb and drus cr commands.
step-4 in this case, some files are still into 's3fs_file' table. During cache clear, this table trying to find files on UAT environment /bucket and it was failed so these styles files are deleted. 

Still it is in investigation mode and trying to reproduce it.  Could you please share your thoughts on it?